# Debian Cinnamon vs Mint Cinnamon documentation

Tags: debian, cinnamon, documentation

I want to better understand how to customize and use Debian Cinnamon.

1) Should I be using the Mint Cinnamon documentation, forums, and the like for my Debian Cinnamon, or is there a better source for this information that makes more sense for Debian Cinnamon users?

2) Also, how different is Debian Cinnamon from Mint Cinnamon?

**I ask this because** as I search the web for help with my Debian Cinnamon, I am finding tons of stuff for Mint Cinnamon and much less stuff for Debian Cinnamon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cinnamon is fully developed by Mint, Debian cinnamon team is only repackaging it. If the version number is the same, then the documention is also the same. There can be very little differences, but i think these wouldn't affect you.